# why is full calendar jquery plugin not working as expected when I click next or previous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I´m using the full calendar plugin, so I load my data for the current month, but when I click previous, then next then previous again; my previous events get duplicated.
For example, if I had an event with id=1 in november, and I´m in december and I go to november; then I see my event with id=1 duplicated.
Here is my json:

```
[{"id":2024,"title":"titulo0","start":"2014-12-23 19:22:17","end":"2014-12-23 19:22:17","description":"descripcion0"}]
```

Here is how I load my calendar:

```
function loadEventos() {
    var current_url = '';
    var new_url     = '';   
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: '/pushCombos/calendarioAction!getEventosMes.action?mes=' + 1,   
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },               
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function() {
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },    
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {     
            calEvent.title = "CLICKED!";
            console.log(moment(calEvent.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
            editarEvento(calEvent);
            console.log(moment(calEvent.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
        }
    }); 
}
```

and here is the code of my buttons:

```
$('.fc-button-group').children().eq(1).click(function(){
    var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
    var month_int = moment(date).format("MM");
    var year_int = moment(date).format("YYYY");
    var events = {
            url: '/pushCombos/calendarioAction!getEventosMes.action?mes=1',
            data: {
                month: month_int,
                year: year_int
            }                                   
    };  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
});
```

When I edit an event and reload it; it reloads fine, but if I use the next and previous buttons, the events get duplicated.
Why is this happening??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your events option to this:

```
events: { 
    url: '/pushCombos/calendarioAction!getEventosMes.action',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        mes: 1
    },
    cache: false,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) { //whatever you want }
}
```

Comment: if this worked; please choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this plugin automatically does the post when you press the previous button that why it was duplicating the events.
Another weird thing I found is that the first day of the month and the last day of the month it sends to the server are wrong.